# Can I specify which variables I want to persist beyond the completion of an await continuation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, c#-5.0

Within an `async` method, any local variables are stored away so that when whatever thread continues after the `await` will have access to the values. Is there any way to indicate which values are really needed after the `await`?

For example:

```
var firstName = "Karl";
var lastName = "Anderson";
var street1 = "123 Nowhere Street";
var street2 = "Apt 1-A";
var city = "Beverly Hills";
var state = "California";
var zip = "90210";

await MyTaskHere();

Console.WriteLine(firstName);
Console.WriteLine(city);
```

So I have declared 7 local variables, but only use 2 of them after the `await`, is there any attribute I can decorate my variables with to indicate that I intend to only use `firstName` and `city` after the `await` completes?

Note: This is a contrived example, but it seems like it might be beneficial to be able to curb the storage of potentially large data chunks if they are not needed when the next thread comes to finish the work.

Comment: I think this thing is better left to the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot. (Other than the obvious solutions of splitting them up into separate methods or setting them to `null`).

The compiler is not fully optimized in this scenario; it may capture more variables than it needs and may hold onto them longer than necessary. This is probably something Microsoft will optimize in the future.

Comment: Maybe they will address it in C# 6, will wait and see. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can run `Ildasm.exe` on your program to see what code the compiler generates. I've tried to do this but unfortunately my IL skills are a bit lacking, however you can see that all the local variables are captured as fields of the generated `<Foo>d__0` class. Given this program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncCaptureVariables
{
    class Program
    {
        public async Task Foo()
        {
            var firstName = "Karl";
            var lastName = "Anderson";
            var street1 = "123 Nowhere Street";
            var street2 = "Apt 1-A";
            var city = "Beverly Hills";
            var state = "California";
            var zip = "90210";

            await Task.Delay(5000);

            Console.WriteLine(firstName);
            Console.WriteLine(city);
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var program = new Program();
            Task t = program.Foo();
            t.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler generates something like the following partially converted to C# code:

```
using System;

class Program : System.Object
{
class <Foo>d__0 : System.ValueType, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine
  {   
    public int32 <>1__state;
    public System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder;
    public class AsyncCaptureVariables.Program <>4__this;
    public string <firstName>5__1;
    public string <lastName>5__2;
    public string <street1>5__3;
    public string <street2>5__4;
    public string <city>5__5;
    public string <state>5__6;
    public string <zip>5__7;
    private System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter <>u__$awaiter8;
    private object <>t__stack;

    void  MoveNext()
    {      
      try
      {      
        IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1
                IL_0001:  stloc.0
                IL_0002:  ldarg.0
                IL_0003:  ldfld      int32 AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/'<Foo>d__0'::'<>1__state'
                IL_0008:  stloc.2
                IL_0009:  ldloc.2
                IL_000a:  ldc.i4.s   -3
                IL_000c:  beq.s      IL_0014

                IL_000e:  ldloc.2
                IL_000f:  ldc.i4.0
                IL_0010:  beq.s      IL_0019

                IL_0012:  br.s       IL_001e

                IL_0014:  br         IL_00ee

                IL_0019:  br         IL_00a8

                IL_001e:  br.s       IL_0020

        //000009:         {
                IL_0020:  nop
        //000010:             var firstName = "Karl";
                IL_0021:  ldarg.0
                IL_0022:  ldstr      "Karl"
                IL_0027:  stfld      string AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/'<Foo>d__0'::'<firstName>5__1'
        //000011:             var lastName = "Anderson";
                IL_002c:  ldarg.0
                IL_002d:  ldstr      "Anderson"
                IL_0032:  stfld      string AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/'<Foo>d__0'::'<lastName>5__2'
        //000012:             var street1 = "123 Nowhere Street";
                IL_0037:  ldarg.0
                IL_0038:  ldstr      "123 Nowhere Street"
                IL_003d:  stfld      string AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/'<Foo>d__0'::'<street1>5__3'
        //000013:             var street2 = "Apt 1-A";
                IL_0042:  ldarg.0
                IL_0043:  ldstr      "Apt 1-A"
                IL_0048:  stfld      string AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/'<Foo>d__0'::'<street2>5__4'
        //000014:             var city = "Beverly Hills";
                IL_004d:  ldarg.0
                IL_004e:  ldstr      "Beverly Hills"
                IL_0053:  stfld      string AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/'<Foo>d__0'::'<city>5__5'
        //000015:             var state = "California";
                IL_0058:  ldarg.0
                IL_0059:  ldstr      "California"
                IL_005e:  stfld      string AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/'<Foo>d__0'::'<state>5__6'
        //000016:             var zip = "90210";
                IL_0063:  ldarg.0
                IL_0064:  ldstr      "90210"
                IL_0069:  stfld      string AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/'<Foo>d__0'::'<zip>5__7'
        //000017: 
        //000018:             await Task.Delay(5000);
                IL_006e:  ldc.i4     0x1388
                IL_0073:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::Delay(int32)
                IL_0078:  callvirt   instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::GetAwaiter()
                IL_007d:  stloc.3
        IL_0078:  callvirt   instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::GetAwaiter()
        IL_007d:  stloc.3
        IL_007e:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0001
        IL_0080:  call       instance bool [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter::get_IsCompleted()
        IL_0085:  brtrue.s   IL_00c6

        IL_0087:  ldarg.0
        IL_0088:  ldc.i4.0
        IL_0089:  stfld      int32 AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>1__state
        IL_008e:  ldarg.0
        IL_008f:  ldloc.3
        IL_0090:  stfld      valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>u__$awaiter8
        IL_0095:  ldarg.0
        IL_0096:  ldflda     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>t__builder
        IL_009b:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0001
        IL_009d:  ldarg.0
        IL_009e:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter,valuetype AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0>(!!0&,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         !!1&)
        IL_00a3:  nop
        IL_00a4:  ldc.i4.0
        IL_00a5:  stloc.0
        IL_00a6:  leave.s    IL_011d

        IL_00a8:  ldarg.0
        IL_00a9:  ldfld      valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>u__$awaiter8
        IL_00ae:  stloc.3
        IL_00af:  ldarg.0
        IL_00b0:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0002
        IL_00b2:  initobj    [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter
        IL_00b8:  ldloc.s    CS$0$0002
        IL_00ba:  stfld      valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>u__$awaiter8
        IL_00bf:  ldarg.0
        IL_00c0:  ldc.i4.m1
        IL_00c1:  stfld      int32 AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>1__state
        IL_00c6:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0001
        IL_00c8:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter::GetResult()
        IL_00cd:  nop
        IL_00ce:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0001
        IL_00d0:  initobj    [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter
//000019: 
//000020:             Console.WriteLine(firstName);
        IL_00d6:  ldarg.0
        IL_00d7:  ldfld      string AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<firstName>5__1
        IL_00dc:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_00e1:  nop
//000021:             Console.WriteLine(city);
        IL_00e2:  ldarg.0
        IL_00e3:  ldfld      string AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<city>5__5
        IL_00e8:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_00ed:  nop
//000022:         }
//000023: 
//000024:         public static void Main()
//000025:         {
//000026:             var program = new Program();
//000027:             Task t = program.Foo();
//000028:             t.Wait();
//000029:         }
//000030:     }
//000031: }
        IL_00ee:  leave.s    IL_0108

      }  // end .try
      catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
      {
        IL_00f0:  stloc.1
        IL_00f1:  ldarg.0
        IL_00f2:  ldc.i4.s   -2
        IL_00f4:  stfld      int32 AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>1__state
        IL_00f9:  ldarg.0
        IL_00fa:  ldflda     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>t__builder
        IL_00ff:  ldloc.1
        IL_0100:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::SetException(class [mscorlib]System.Exception)
        IL_0105:  nop
        IL_0106:  leave.s    IL_011d

      }  // end handler
      IL_0108:  nop
//000022:         }
      IL_0109:  ldarg.0
      IL_010a:  ldc.i4.s   -2
      IL_010c:  stfld      int32 AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>1__state
//000023: 
//000024:         public static void Main()
//000025:         {
//000026:             var program = new Program();
//000027:             Task t = program.Foo();
//000028:             t.Wait();
//000029:         }
//000030:     }
//000031: }
      IL_0111:  ldarg.0
      IL_0112:  ldflda     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>t__builder
      IL_0117:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::SetResult()
      IL_011c:  nop
      IL_011d:  nop
      IL_011e:  ret
    } // end of method <Foo>d__0::MoveNext

    .method private hidebysig newslot virtual final 
            instance void  SetStateMachine(class [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine param0) cil managed
    {
      .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
      .override [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine::SetStateMachine
      // Code size       13 (0xd)
      .maxstack  8
      IL_0000:  ldarg.0
      IL_0001:  ldflda     valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder AsyncCaptureVariables.Program/<Foo>d__0::<>t__builder
      IL_0006:  ldarg.1
      IL_0007:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::SetStateMachine(class [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine)
      IL_000c:  ret
    } // end of method <Foo>d__0::SetStateMachine

  } // end of class <Foo>d__0
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed breakdown of what is going on behind the scenes, did not realize a state machine was used to store the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can create scopes by added braces in the code, but whenever something is not referenced anymore compiler will collect that anyways. do this

```
{  //start of scope
    var firstName = "Karl";
    var lastName = "Anderson";
    var street1 = "123 Nowhere Street";
    var street2 = "Apt 1-A";
    var city = "Beverly Hills";
    var state = "California";
    var zip = "90210";

    await MyTaskHere();
}//end of scope
```

There are other things that might be taken into consideration like if you can create methods to logically divide things than in my opinion that is a better option. Though there is no harm in doing it this way either.

Comment: Adding a scope does not cause anything to be set to null. The locals aren't even really locals any more. They are transformed into fields on a compiler generated implementation of `IAsyncStateMachine`.

Comment: Lets call it this way, as the variables will go out of scope after the closing bracket therefore they will be good for GC to be collected.

Comment: {string test = "abc";}   Console.WriteLine(test);  Try this and let me have your thoughts

Comment: Scope is about where in the program text some entity can be referred to by name. This is completely different than when the contents of some reference are eligible for collection. Your example doesn't compile, so I'm not sure what it proves. Try this `Func<string> f; { string x = "abc"; f = () => x; } Console.WriteLine(f());`. Is your claim that somehow the string referenced by `x` ("abc") will be garbage collected at the `}`? Because that seems to be the claim you are making about scopes and it is false.

Comment: Actually, this won't work, at least not with the current compiler. The variable won't be accessible, but the field of the state machine *won't* be set to `null`, so the object won't be GCed.

Comment: No Mike i am not claiming it will be GCed but it will be eligible to be GCed. That is all i am saying. And sooner the better. OR am i missing something?

Comment: @EhsanUllah No, it won't be eligible for GC. In mike's case because the closure requires that. In the `async` case, because the compiler does not `null` out the fields.

Comment: @EhsanUllah Like I said, the object won't become eligible for collection when you say it will. The claim that “whenever something is not used compiler will collect that anyways” is not true for `async` methods.

Comment: @svick that is not my claim at all (not atleast what i meant). but after the call back it will be. won't it?

Comment: @EhsanUllah No, it won't, that's my point. Try to compile your method and look at the generated code of the state machine in decompiler. You will see that the fields are *not* automatically nulled out and so they won't become eligible for GC when they go out of scope.

Comment: yeah they are not, but still are accessible for GC. are they or are they not?